# A good literature for statistical learning theory?

Tags: machine-learning, references

Any recommendations for good literature on statistical learning theory? I mean, something what goes into more details than Elements of Statistical Learning, in terms of losses, empirical error estimation etc.

Comment: We have a number of questions which provide machine learning references. Even if the *questions* themselves aren't duplicates of this, the *answer content* will end up containing mostly the same books just because the field isn't really overburdened with English-language graduate-level texts. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references+machine-learning